# Cannot parse constant error in SQL and Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, data-conversion, spring-boot-maven-plugin

SpringBoot bug, that occurs when i try to insert a values into SQL "expense" table.

```
import java.time.Instant;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="expense")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Instant expensedate;

    private String description;

    private String location;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private User user1;
}
```

I have this expense.java (User and Category are also separate files) file and when i try to

```
insert into expense values (100,'New York Business Trip','2019-06-16T17:00:00.000Z','New York',1,1)
```

i get this error for some reason:

```
Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" constant "New York Business Trip";
```

im pretty new at this, so explain it if you find a bug please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a string value inside the Instant column, so that's why you are getting this issue.

```
insert into expense values (100, '2019-06-16T17:00:00.000Z', 'New York Business Trip', 'New York', 1, 1)
```

Not sure what's the inside the category class so you need to pass the value for it.

Comment: it still doesnt work, but i get the
` ` `
Data conversion error converting "'New York Business Trip' (EXPENSE: ""ID"" BIGINT NOT NULL)";
` ` `
and im again not sure what that means